# Nowadays, is there still any sense in adding prefixes like "-moz" and "-webkit" in front of the properties of some css elements?

Tags: css, web

For exemple in these following statements:

```
animation: closing 3s steps(90) forwards;
-webkit-animation: closing 3s steps(90) forwards;
-moz-animation: closing 3s steps(90) forwards;

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), rgba(255,255,0,0.5));
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), rgba(255,255,0,0.5));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), rgba(255,255,0,0.5));
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,0,0,0.65), rgba(255,255,0,0.65));
```

Comment: Check out caniuse.com

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, there is absolutely no point in adding them manually. You should write clean (S)CSS and run it through a post-css task in your favorite JavaScript task runner.

Most people use `autoprefixer` (it's really good), which and adds all the necessary prefixes to your code based on your settings. If running a post-css task seems too complicated (it really isn't!), autoprefixer is also available [online](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

For maximum compatibility, use `> 0%` in the filter box (below).

---

If you're asking if they are still required by browsers, well, yes: there is a considerable amount of proprietary attributes only recognized by one browser.